# How to schedule a job on Azure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, parsing, azure, scheduled-tasks

So here is my requirement,

I have a service provider that generates a files with data in a proprietary format on a text file. I have to download the file, parse it, then process it for specific records, and then update the database accordingly. The process needs to run multiple times on specific days (mostly Mondays & Fridays).

I am using Windows Azure platform. My website is hosted on azure & using SQL Server as my database. Using C# to create the database updater app.

What is the best approach to schedule a database updater job? Do I even need the updater application to be written on there is some better way to achieve the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided I'd start by exploring Web Jobs (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx).

Web Jobs allow you to create a schedule jobs that will run for you at intervals or continually.